# Does Clara realise she is a Primordial?

Tags: image-comics, death-vigil

In the very first pages of [*Death Vigil*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ComicBook/DeathVigil) by [Stjepan Sejic](http://nebezial.deviantart.com/), [Clara is sacrificed](http://nebezial.deviantart.com/art/death-vigil-page-17-and-18-426897620) by her [now ex-] boyfriend to summon a Primordial using a Dreamer's Sigil.

In the beginning, she is too surprised by everything, and it is clearly seen that she doesn't know anything about this stuff prior to this experience.

However, after she becomes a Vigil and starts going to missions, it becomes apparent that there is more to her than meets the eye.

Necromancers recognise her as a primordial:

[image]

But it doesn't seem she is aware of that.

There are, however, some lines that can be interpreted to indicate her awareness that there is *someone else* bound to her:

[image]

Notice her use of "we" instead of "I". Same in this panel:

[image]

It would *seem* that she says "we" only when the Primordial's powers are used: the Primordial awakens and his/her personality merges with Clara's.

One other point is her noted absence after she goes to fight powerful necromancers alone. She is beaten, but then the Primordial awakens and kills the bad guys... and Clara says she "passed out" or "took a nap":

[image]

I could attribute this first panel (after her fight with Lord Asrah) to actually passing out. But in the next panel, where she is stabbed by Wulf, there is no way she wouldn't remember this:

[image]

And yet, after the Primordial destroys Wulf, she says she simply passed out:

[image]

When I read this, I couldn't shrug the feeling that Clara knows she hosts a Primordial (at least now), and hides it to... well, I don't know.

Is there actual evidence, or confirmation by the author, that Clara *knows* she is bound to a primordial?

Comment: Could the Primordial be manipulating her memories?

Comment: @Adamant It could be. We've not seen anything like it before, since all the Primordials shown don't even have a personality - they've been completely assimilated by their human hosts, which is why _I_ think Clara _might_ be hiding it. But Primordials seem to have some memory-related powers (or rather Necromancers do).